# Mariadb can't restart|start

Tags: mysql, centos, innodb, mariadb

systemctl status mysql brings this up.

> Jan 02 13:05:10 CentOS-production mysqld[31513]: InnoDB: Error number 11 means 'Resource temporarily unavailable'.
>
> Jan 02 12:31:36 CentOS-production mysqld[31394]: InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at
>
> Jan 02 12:31:36 CentOS-production mysqld[31394]: InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/operating-system-error-codes.html
>
> Jan 02 12:31:36 CentOS-production mysqld[31394]: 2017-01-02 12:31:36 139852839635200 [ERROR] InnoDB: Can't open './ibdata1'
>
> Jan 02 12:31:36 CentOS-production mysqld[31394]: 2017-01-02 12:31:36 139852839635200 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not open or create the system tablespace. If you tried to add new data files to...
>
> Jan 02 12:31:36 CentOS-production mysqld[31394]: 2017-01-02 12:31:36 139852839635200 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
>
> Jan 02 12:31:36 CentOS-production mysqld[31394]: 2017-01-02 12:31:36 139852839635200 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
>
> Jan 02 12:31:36 CentOS-production systemd[1]: mariadb.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
>
> Jan 02 12:31:36 CentOS-production systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB database server.

MariaDB log says:

> 161222 16:38:06 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid ended

I am working on a newest version of mariadb and I don't have any data in it.
What am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Is there an instance of MariaDB already open? (Try *ps ax|grep mysqld*, or check with *lsof* if any process is holding the file open.)

Several years ago, I implemented advisory file locking to prevent multiple InnoDB instances from accessing the same files:

```
commit 09fc359480135997b0a5ea831d42ab7497f129be
Author: marko@hundin.mysql.fi <>
Date:   Wed May 5 11:40:17 2004 +0300

    InnoDB: os0file.c: Lock files exclusively (Bug #3608)
```

While the output of that check was not included in the error log output, I suspect that it is there.